# Why does the 17 character of my output string get replaced with an 'o'?

Tags: c, math

I was trying to write a simple code that evaluates simple mathematical expressions and I just stumbled across this error. I tried various ways to find the issue, but I couldn't.
It seems fine to me, but when I execute it, it replaces the 17 character (index 16) of the string 'res' with an 'o' or it just deletes it.

This piece of code is what I wrote to convert from Infix to Postfix expression :

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * ascan()
{
    char * s, c;
    int len = -1;

    s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    while (scanf("%c", &c) == 1)
    {
        if(c == '\n')
            break;
        len += 1;
        s = (char *)realloc(s, (len + 1));
        s[len] = c;
        s[len + 1] = '\0';
    }

    return s;
}

char * chcpy(char * str, char chr)
{
    int len = strlen(str);

    str[len] = chr;
    str = (char *)realloc(str, (len + 1));
    str[len + 1] = '\0';
    len++;

    return str;
}

typedef struct stack stack;
struct stack
{
    char opr;
    stack * pre;
};

stack * createStack()
{
    stack * stk;

    stk = NULL;

    return stk;
}

stack * push(stack * top, char opr)
{
    stack * new = (stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    new -> opr = opr;

    new -> pre = top;
    top = new;

    return top;
}

char pop(stack ** top)
{
    if ((*top) != NULL)
    {
        char opr = (*top) -> opr;

        stack * tmp = (*top);
        (*top) = (*top) -> pre;
        free(tmp);

        return opr;
    }

    return '\0';
}

char * evaluatePostfix(char * exp)
{
    char * pfe = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    stack * ops = createStack();
    int i = 0, p = 0;

    while (exp[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (exp[i] == '(')
            p++;
        else if (isdigit(exp[i]))
            pfe = chcpy(pfe, *(exp + i));
        else if (exp[i] == ')')
        {
            p--;

            if (ops != NULL)
            {
                pfe = chcpy(pfe, ' ');
                pfe = chcpy(pfe, pop(&ops));
            }
        }
        else if (exp[i] == '+' || exp[i] == '-' || exp[i] == '*' || exp[i] == '/')
        {
            pfe = chcpy(pfe, ' ');

            ops = push(ops, exp[i]);
        }

        i++;
    }

    while (ops != NULL)
    {
        pfe = chcpy(pfe, ' ');
        pfe = chcpy(pfe, pop(&ops));
    }

    if (p < 0)
        return NULL;

    return pfe;
}

int main()
{
    char * exp = ascan(), * res;

    res = evaluatePostfix(exp);

    printf("%s\n", res);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't really know why it affects only that exact character, and I don't know if it's exactly an allocation bug, but if it is please help me solve it.

Input :

```
10*(2+8*(3-2))
```

Output :

```
10 2 8 3 2 - * +o*
                ^
```

Comment: what is the expression you try to calculate?

Comment: @AsafItach I just added an example of an input with the output

Comment: @AsafItach yeah the problem was the null character. Btw sorry for not including ascan() I didn't think it would be useful to post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    int len = strlen(str);
>
>    *(str + len) = chr;
>    str = (char *)realloc(str, (len + 1));
>    *(str + len + 1) = '\0';
> ```

Here you write the terminating null character beyond the end of allocated memory. Corrected:

```
    int len = strlen(str);
    str[len++] = chr;
    str = realloc(str, len + 1);
    str[len] = '\0';
    return str;
```

And there's another issue - you forgot to initialize `*pfe = '\0';` in `evaluatePostfix` before appending to it .

Comment: Also see other issue.

Comment: Yes thank you, I didn't notice the other one.

Comment: Btw why does it print 'o' exactly and not another character, I tried different inputs and it's always an 'o'.

Comment: This could be analyzed in an execution environment where the error manifests itself in the way you describe, which is only one of many possible behaviors. My system doesn't behave that way, so I'm sorry, I can't find the reason for your observation.